# Snake Cased names for enum values

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there any built in functionality in `Newtonsoft.Json` for serializing enum values into their snake-cased names?

currently, I am providing values manually:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum MyEnum {
    [EnumMember(Value = "value_one")]
    ValueOne,
}
```

Comment: How about using a SnakeCaseNamingStrategy for your enums? Example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Didn't test that because I shouldn't use any serialization settings in my proj. All attribs should be provided on POCOs I use as DTO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Optional snake-casing of enum values has been implemented in Json.NET [12.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/12.0.1).  It is now possible to specify a [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm) for [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter_NamingStrategy.htm):

> New feature - Added support for NamingStrategy to StringEnumConverter

Thus you can pass [`SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.htm) into any of several of the [constructors](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor.htm) for `StringEnumConverter`, e.g. [`new StringEnumConverter(typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor_3.htm).

Using this, you can now specify that enums should be snake-cased globally when serialized by adding an appropriate converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new StringEnumConverter(typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy)) },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyEnum.ValueOne, settings);

Assert.IsTrue(json == "\"value_one\""); // Passes successfully
```

Or, alternatively, `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` can be applied to select enums as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter), typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
enum MyEnum
{
    ValueOne,
    // Other values...
}
```

For further information see [Issue  #1862: [Feature] StringEnumConverter takes a NamingStrategy argument](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1862).